# Powershell execution in Octopus

Tags: powershell, batch-file, octopus-deploy, octopus

I have a powershell file test.ps1 which takes 3 parameters. I am trying to call/execute this file from a script step/task in octopus.

Can I do this, if I can how to achieve this.

I tried a few things to achieve this.

1. Use a batch file (test.bat) powershell E:\somefolder\test.ps1 %1 %2 %3 to call the below in the script task in octopus to execute this E:\somefolder\test.bat p1 p2 p3

The above does not work and says cmdlet does not identify the command.

2. Use the ps1 file itself i.e. call E:\somefolder\test.ps1 p1 p2 p3 to call in the script task in octopus.

This gives the same error as above.

I changed the code a little bit to use param([string]$param1, [string]$param2, [string]$param3) and then I get the parameter cannot be found.

Can someone please help me with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Octopus Deploy you can use a "Run Script" step to execute scripts. This step is designed to execute PowerShell on the deployment target, which removes the need to find ways of kicking of the script. It also means that the step becomes part of the deployment process and you can end the deployment if it fails.

In the nextversion of Octopus Deploy (v3.3) [you can have your PowerShell script in source control](https://octopus.com/blog/octopus-deploy-3.3), or you can edit the script in the step itself. You have access to project variables and Octopus system variables in the script.

In previous versions, only the option to edit the script within the step was available.

Go to your Project's process in Ocotpus Deploy and...

1. Click "Add step"
2. Select "Run a Script"
3. Give it a name and enter the PowerShell script
4. Add any conditions
5. Click "Save"

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I already have a script step, the thing is there is a set of repeating script which I want to avoid and have it in a file and invoke/call it inside the script step. TO make it more maintainable.

Comment: Can you describe the script a bit more - it could probably be piped or looped to do what you need.